# Switch between a table view and a list / grid / card view

Tags: javascript, listview, gridview, model-view-controller, tableview

I need to display data on a website in a table with the option to switch to a list or grid view (don't know the term).

I have searched endlessly online. (Please also keep in mind that I am very new to programming, so my jargon may be incorrect).

I want to display data on a website with the option to view as a table pr as a list/grid/card view. This site has the exact view options I want to include on my site: http://railscasts.com/?type=free&view=list ... I don't need the 'grid view' that just has the images though, I just want to learn how to do the 'full view' and 'list view'.

I appreciate any help! Whether actual code or a link to another page on this topic or suggestions on how to search for the answer to my question!

Comment: Let's see what you've tried so far.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between a "table" and a "grid". I mean, a table is a list of rows, each of which has a list of columns. Isn't that the same thing as a "grid"?